# Temporary objects in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, struct, constructor, temporary-objects

**C code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
}A;

int main()
{
    A(); // this line gives error
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Error: Expected identifier or '('
```

**C++ code**

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;

    A()
    {
        std::cout<<"Ctor-A\n";
    }

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout<<"Dctor-A\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A(); // creates temporary object and destroyed it 
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Ctor-A
Dctor-A
```

I know about the "Rule of three", but code becomes complicated and most compilers don't give errors if we don't follow the rule. So I avoided creation of a copy constructor and an overloaded assignment operator.

Why does `A()/A{}` create a temporary object in C++, but not in C? What's another way to create a temporary object in C?

Comment: There are no constructors in C.

Comment: Structs don’t have constructors in C, so, there’s nothing to temporary.  The closest thing is to just do “A a” and you’ll get a stack allocated A.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to create an anonymous temporary in C. Why do you want to out of curiosity?

Comment: C syntax for an anonymous temporary looks something like `(A){}`, that is, it is based on the cast syntax.  C supports only one cast grammar, while C++ supports 6 (if I haven't missed any).

Comment: Found some documentation, it is called [Compound Literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) and it can be used with structures.

Comment: @BenVoigt the irony is that the parens actually sets up a most vexing parse too, they'd be better off with initializer list/c syntax.

Comment: @BenVoigt `(A){}` compiler telling about this line " `Expression result unused` "

Comment: @AbhishekMane: Ok, that is true and a warning is reasonable.  The expression result isn't being used in C++ either.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow what's the connection between temporary object and constructor ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane: There isn't such a connection in C.  But the syntax `A()` you are using in C++ is a function-style cast/constructor invocation.  C doesn't have function-style casts.

Comment: @AbhishekMane I was speaking about the construction A().

Comment: @BenVoigt "*based on the cast syntax*" you mentioned this regarding `(A){}` can you tell more about that ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane: Do you see the link in my comment below the one you are asking about?

Comment: @BenVoigt I will check.

Comment: @Max what's the connection between temporary object and constructor ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane I am not a language lawyer, but the concept of temporaries comes with the territory of C++ objects _because_ they can have code that runs on creation and destruction, and the concept of a temporary was useful in that sense.  Without destructors, there is much less need for “temporaries” to run them quickly, and afaik C has no storage class similar to temporary because it’d be redundant.  Automatic storage duration handles all cases since “a bag of data” sitting around until the closing brace doesn’t change the effect of the code.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Compound literals are not temporaries in C. Those outside a function definition have static storage duration, and those inside have automatic storage duration with the usual lifetime. The only temporary in C is a non-lvalue structure or union containing an array. Such a temporary can be created by a function that returns such a structure or union (by value). Its lifetime ends when evaluation of the containing full expression ends.

Answer (score 3):

In C (C99 and later) you can create a structure with automatic lifetime using a [Compound Literal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html).

The syntax is `(A){ initializers, for, struct, members }`.

The lifetime is automatic, not temporary, so the structure created in this way does not vanish at the end of the full-expression, but at the end of the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 3):

This expression

```
A()
```

is considered by C compilers as a function call. In C++ such an expression means a call of a constructor provided that A is a class type.

To create a temporary object in C you could declare a function like for example

```
struct A { int a; } A( int x )
{
    struct A a = { .a = x };
    return a;
}
```

and then you can call the function creating a temporary object of the type struct A like

```
A( 10 );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A { int a; } A( int x )
{
    struct A a = { .a = x };
    return a;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct A a = A( 10 );
    
    printf( "a.a = %d\n", a.a );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a.a = 10
```

Comment: you could even compress the code a bit without loosing readability with `return (struct A) { .a = x };`. Anyway, consider using `A(void)` to use `A` in a way similar the OP did.

Answer (score 0):

`A()` calls the constructor for the struct A in the C++ code. However, C doesn't support constructors / destructors, or even objects (in the sense of OOP) in fact. The only way to create a temporary object as you describe in C would be to declare a variable of type A and wait for it to go out of scope, where the memory allocated for it will be popped from the stack, or to allocate a variable on the heap and free it in the next line.

Comment: C [programs consist from objects of different types.

Comment: C doesn't support classes or object oriented programming, structs are the closest that C has.

Comment: What is the relation between objects in C and  the object oriented programming? You wrote that C does not support objects. It is an invalid statement.

Comment: C doesn't support objects . An object oriented programming language is one that supports objects. C is not one of these. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/113535

Comment: Dylan Burn C supports objects. All C program consist from objects and their manipulations. You have taken a term from other context and are trying to substitute the term object in C. Your statements are invalid.

Comment: ["C programs create, destroy, access, and manipulate objects"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object). Just because they're not OOP objects doesn't mean they are not objects.

Comment: Sorry, I will change my answer to specify that C doesn't support OOP objects, as these are the objects in question